# How do I pull a foreign key from the database using the DataGridColumn that Blazorise provides?

Tags: datagrid, visual-studio-2022, datagridcolumn

**DataGridColumn which I have housed within a <DataGrid/>:**

<DataGridColumn TItem="Ticket" Field="@nameof(Ticket.Department.DepartmentName)" Caption="Department Name" Editable="true" />

**this is my code block:**
@code {

```
private List<Department> ?Departments { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    await TicketService.GetTickets();
    await TicketService.GetDepartments();

}
```

}

**ticket and department models:**

```
    public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Boolean IsActive { get; set; } = true;     
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public Department? Department { get; set; }//
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

VS2022 complies the code fine but after I deploy the page this error on developer console appears:

"Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot detect the member of BlazorFullStackCrud.Shared.Ticket (Parameter 'DepartmentName')"

I am accessing a foreign key and Blazorise does not seem to want to fetch it from the database